# How i can update document in Firestore kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[This image show my firestore documents which that auto generated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofw9q.jpg)[Which i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPm94.jpg)
//I want to update or merge Firestore document without adding new document. So i want to image url to firestore existing document field with merge method. But it does not overwrite, it is going to create a new document with auto-generated ID. How i can fix it?

```
val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
val imageName = "$uuid.jpg"

val reference = storage.reference
val imagereference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

if (selectedPicture != null) {
    imagereference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener {
        val uid =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val uploadPictureReference = storage.reference.child("images").child(imageName)
        uploadPictureReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            val downloadUrl = it.toString()

            if (uid != null) {

                val postMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                postMap.put("downloadUs", downloadUrl)
                postMap.put("Email", auth.currentUser!!.email!!)
                postMap.put("date", Timestamp.now())

                val new = firestore.collection("ProfPic").document(uid)
                new.set(postMap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener {  }.
                addOnFailureListener { Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, it.localizedMessage, Toast
                    .LENGTH_LONG).show() }
```

Comment: When you're using this line of code `new.set(postMap, SetOptions.merge())`, the document does exist or nor?

Comment: Thanks for response, Sir. It is goint to create new document with another auto-generated id. When i put there custom id like "
1hcumCduqGgpFcdr54z8" it works correctly. But i need to use id uid to recognize the current user

Comment: If there a document which created in another activity it show document. But this activity i need merge or update field in existing document

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Can you please prove how that code generates different documents?

Comment: Sir i uploaded my question part image that shows my firestore document and collection paths

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot see any `Users` collection.